# ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : multi-tenant restricted to certain issuers

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API that is going to be multi tenant, this is all working but I need to restrict the issuers to a select list.

I tried doing it like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = new[] { "XXX", "YYY" };
        })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()      
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

But I get an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Bearer.

I've also tried adding something similar at the `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi` call, but it seems to have no effect.   What am I missing?

Comment: // Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);

        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = $"XXX";
    }, options => { builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options); }); does NOT error out, but it doesn't validate the token, I can pass anything in here.

Comment: The error says you have more than one schemes with the same name. make sure you have added builder.Services.AddAuthorization();app.UseAuthentication();app.UseAuthorization(); . try adding code for logging `builder.Logging.AddDebug();
builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => 
{  loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
    loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
});` this can give more insight  if the token is being read and if any errors occur during the validation process .instead of single user check use code   ValidIssuers = new[] { "XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ" },

Comment: Logging didn't add anything useful.  I think I need to pull .AddJwtBearer  as its redundant with .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi.   But when I try to set valid issuers in .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi all of that is ignored

Comment: I never did get this to work, but as a work around I hooked into the token validation event.